# Hiding imported data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I'm importing data from another sheet using =IMPORTRANGE, is there any way to hide the imported data but still reference it for that sheet? If so, how?

The way I'm doing it now: =IMPORTRANGE("URL REDACTED","Signups!A1:O9")

Comment: If you share more details, you might get an answer that better fits your needs. I.E. Are you looking to save visual space because you have too many tabs? Are you concerned about users accidentally messing with the import formula?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Import *all* the data into a new `'Import'` sheet, and refer to that sheet in your formulas. Then hide the `'Import'` sheet.

Note that a determined user can always discover all contents in a spreadsheet they have access to. Hiding data does not guarantee that it will not be seen.

Comment: As an alternative to hiding the sheet, it could be possible to hide only the rows, but only the columns / rows but this option might not be as convenient as hiding the sheet. I'm just mentioning them for the sake of completeness.